# Azure Synapse Serverless Pool Database Error: Lock request time out period exceeded Error:1222

Tags: ssms, azure-synapse

When I attempt to delete a view in Serverless Pool Database from SSMS Version 18.4 I get the following error:

Lock request time out period exceeded Error:1222

[image]

Can someone let me know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lock request time out period exceeded Error:1222

A query waits longer than the lock timeout setting, as shown by the error message "lock request time out period exceeded" (error 1222). The lock timeout parameter controls the amount of time, in milliseconds, that a query must wait before returning an error on a blocked resource.

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions where open_transaction_count=1;
```

The above query obtains active transaction information for the current database using **sys.dm_exec_sessions** view.

[image]

Then kill that process using the following command.

```sql
Kill 129
```

Make sure that every `BEGIN TRANSACTION` contains a `COMMIT` command to avoid this.

The following will indicate success but leave transactions uncommitted:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION
--SQL_CODE?
COMMIT
```

**Closing query windows with uncommitted transactions will prompt you to commit your transactions.**